# How can I debug KCL(python) in python script?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, stream, producer-consumer, amazon-kinesis

I use KCL library for python consumer, but I don't know how can I get data and etc in python script?

It works via MultiLangDaemon and based on java. I have a python script which works above java (I use samples in the library and use `sample_kclpy_app.py`) and when I start java (which was generated by python) I'm not able to get data or print data.

How can I debug it via python script? I tried to start  sample_kclpy_app.py parallel and nothing happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Kinesis Client Library communicates between Java and Python via STDIN / STDOUT, so instead of using `print` statements, debugging can be performed via a Python logging object directed to a file. For example, within `sample_kclpy_app.py`:

Add to the import section:

```
import logging
```

Add to the RecordProcessor `init` method:

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='test.log',
        format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
        datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
        level=logging.DEBUG)
```

Add to the `process_record` method (for a simple logging example):

```
logging.debug('Data: %s', data.decode('utf8'))
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html for more details on the logging module.

Comment: I've notice `logging` outputs are interpreted as commands by Java. The log is printed, but Java catches those and try to run `2020-06-08 22:26:56,436 [multi-lang-daemon-0001] ERROR s.a.k.multilang.DrainChildSTDERRTask [NONE] - Received error line from subprocess [INFO - 2020-06-08 22:26:56,435 - root:main.py(180) - Downloading file tmp/name_identifier] for shard shardId-000000000000
INFO - 2020-06-08 22:26:56,435 - root:main.py(180) - Downloading file tmp/name_identifier`